# Prevent save account details from changing billing meta data in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, meta, user-accounts, billing

I am building my site on woocommerce and by default, when the customer changes his billing information during checkout, this plugin not only saves this new data but also updates the customer USER meta first name or last name with that same name information, so at that moment USER = BILLING. I have managed to prevent this with the following snippet I looked up in another thread:

```html
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_customer','custom_checkout_update_customer', 10, 2 );
function custom_checkout_update_customer( $customer, $data ){

    // Get the user ID
    $user_id = $customer->get_id();

    // Get the default wordpress first name and last name (if they exist)
    $user_first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
    $user_last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );

    // We set the values by defaul worpress ones, before it's saved to DB
    $customer->set_first_name( $user_first_name );
    $customer->set_last_name( $user_last_name );
}
```

Now I need to also prevent something close to the opposite from happening, ie  Woocommerce also updating the billing data when the customer changes his USER first name or last name in the edit account. Basically, I need these two concepts to be apart (Billing and USER). Any ideas?

Comment: As Woocommerce is a Wordpress plugin, it adds "customer" billing and shipping information. Woocommerce Uses existing Wordpress user-data as Billing and can add different shipping information. So billing information is part of the account information, as "customer" user can't access Wordpress backend. So you are just complicating things and making confusions. Nobody do what you are doing… The only thing that can be useful is to have a system that keeps multiple shipping addresses.

Comment: I do not see where is the confusion ... For example, in the backend, in the user page,I can clearly see the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' in the Name section; as well as a different 'First Name' and 'Last Name' in the Billing and in the Shipping section.

Comment: And in the frontend I want to also display those concepts separately.